# jQuery Slider not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I have a jquery slider which is working good in Firefox and Chrome. But its not working on IE. Here is my code

```
 <script type="application/x-javascript">
<!--
  jQuery(function(){
    jQuery("#featured > ul").tabs({fx: {opacity: 'toggle',}}).tabs("rotate", 5000, true);
    jQuery("#contactus, #quote").fancybox({
    'width'           : '75%',
    'height'          : '100%',
    'autoScale'       : false,
    'transitionIn'    : 'none',
    'transitionOut'   : 'none',
    'type'            : 'iframe'
    });
  });
//-->
</script>
```

Any help and suggestions will be highly appreciable.

Comment: Do you have an example online anywhere? Would really help with the debugging!

Comment: which version of IE? Is that issue specific to a particular version or common to IE6,7,8,9?

Comment: What is the error you are getting ? what line number ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internet Explorer does not have trailing commas when defining object literals. I have not tested it as I don't have the browser here, but have you tried removing the extra comma after `opacity : 'toggle'`?